# In a batch file, how do I loop over strings with spaces in them?

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a batch file, how do I loop over strings with spaces in them?

For example, I have:

```
for %%P in (Test 1,Test 2,Test 3) do (
echo %%P
)
```

The output I get is

```
Test
1
Test
2
Test
3
```

instead of the output I am hoping for:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

if I add quotes I get

```
"Test 1"
"Test 2"
"Test 3"
```

which I don't want either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for /?` has your answers.

> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> ```

So you'd implement it like this:

```
FOR %%P IN ("Test 1","Test 2","Test 3") DO (echo %%~P)
```

Comment: This only pulls one item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

@Wes Larson beat me to it, but here are other methods to split the strings without needing individual quotes;

---

Assuming there is only ever 3 strings to split;

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%G in ("Test 1,Test 2,Test 3") do (
    echo %%~G
    echo %%~H
    echo %%~I
)
```

---

Or my favorite;

```
set "string=Test 1,Test 2,Test 3"
set "chVar=%string%"
:reIter
for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%G in ("%chVar%") do (echo %%G & set "chVar=%%H")
if defined chVar (goto :reIter)
```

---

And an odd but optional;

```
set "string=Test 1,Test 2,Test 3"
set string=%string: =_%
for %%G in (%string%) do call :replace "%%~G"
pause
exit

:replace
set "chVar=%~1"
echo %chVar:_= %
goto :eof
```